# Dist folder always appearing

Tags: vscode-extensions

Whenever I create a new project or even open my project in vscode, a .dist folder always creates at the top of the files.
Also how do I remove C Complier terminal runner as it appears there all the time

I have always been deleting the folder whenever I see it.

Comment: While the question is tagged `C`, the problem has nothing to do with the C programming language.  I deleted the `C` tag.  My apologies.  Same thing for `javascript` .

Answer (score 1):

The dist folder may be created because of the extensions you are using, try disabling the extensions one by one and check.

You can close the active terminals in VSCode by clicking on delete button present at top right of the terminal.